# Django Local Environment Settings

Tags: python, django, localhost

i started a new project in Django but local environment settings come from the previous project.

So how can i reset local environment settings?

Thank you..

Answer (score 2):

First, in your project folder create a *virtualenv*:

```
python -m venv .venv
```

Activate your *virtualenv*:

```
source .venv/bin/activate
```

Install Django with your *virtualenv* activated:

```
pip install django
```

Then install [python-decouple](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-decouple):

```
pip install python-decouple
```

It helps you to extract your local settings.

1. Create a *.env* file in your project root
2. Extract all your settings from *settings.py*, example:

**.env**

```
SECRET_KEY=CHANGE_THIS_FOR_YOUR_SECRET_KEY
DEBUG=True
```

**settings.py**

```
from decouple import config

SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')
DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=False, cast=bool)
```

For last, but not less important, add the *.env* file in your *.gitignore*, so any developer who gets your code won't use your local settings.

Answer (score 0):

Started a new project. And you replaced the settings.py from another project? If so just update your database and install the required packages with pip. To update the database: python manage.py makemigrations and then python manage.py migrate.

Comment: Hello, no i didn't replace settings.py. This new one is totally new.

Comment: You don't have to set your environment variable. 1. set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE= 2. django-admin runserver. Run these 2 commands in CMD or Terminal. Do this to reset the environment variable. And create a virtual environment instead, for your future projects. This way nothing will mix up with previous projects.

Comment: yeah i guess this is the correct way but in shell in what directory should i run the set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE= Also should i add something after =. Thank you so much

Comment: It shouldn't matter because it's a static variable. After the '=' sign you do nothing. That should be enough.

Comment: Thank you my friend but it is not working.. I will solve it in coming days then i will write here how i solved it. Thanks again

Comment: That's fine good luck with it. And if you can't figure it out try to give the reader a better understanding of your problem. Just an advice :)